# Python IPC between two processes on different machines

Tags: python, ipc

I have two python processes running on two separate machines. These processes need to communicate with each other using some IPC mechanism.

Which is the simplest or the most suitable IPC mechanism in python?

Comment: recommend http://zeromq.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should have a look at

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#module-xmlrpclib

and

https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html

I prefer RPC over socket communication.

Comment: why do you prefer RPC over socket communication for message passing?

Comment: For me socket programming is a nice way to understand network communication. But for larger projects it's nice to have a middleware. I don't have to care about the communication and can concentrate on my business logic. Furthermore it looks more elegant to run a "local" function instead of messing around with sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket programming for this.
Find out more about this at:

- [Sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)
- [Python networking](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm)